# Counting Unique Values with Contain Critera

Tags: google-sheets

I've searched all over and this simple principle is apparently not so simple.

BTW I'm using Google Sheets which as you probably know has most of the same functionality as Excel, plus an extra function that might be useful in my case: [COUNTUNIQUE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093405?hl=en)

My "Criteria" is two-fold and required for two different expressions:

1. Count the unique values that "contain" a string.
2. Count the unique values that "don't contain" a string.

Consider this data:

```
     A        
1    snapple
2    snapple
3    grapple
4    orange
5    orange
6    peach
```

**Criteria 1:** Say I want to count the unique values in Column A that **contain** the word "apple."

In the data above, it should render "2," knowing it should void duplicates.

**Criteria 2:** Say I want to count the unique values in Column A that **don't contain** the word "apple."

In the data above, it should render "2," knowing it should void duplicates.

Here's a sheet doc to test: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JYZIhZmSuoWoGvmTFFcBAD1EUQVWvosqBQzkGsbwaOI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Nice software specification. If you are 'using Google Sheets' then why the [excel] and [excel-vba] tags?

Comment: Excel has been able to seamlessly transfer to Google Sheets and vice-versa in all of my experiences. I am not aware of any Excel worksheet formulas that cannot be brought to the Google Sheets interface as well. The tags for google-spreadsheet are about a million times less popular. Hope that explains my reasoning to edit the tags back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criteria 1:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(QUERY(A:A,"select A where A contains 'apple'",0)))`

Criteria 2:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(QUERY(A:A,"select A where not(A contains 'apple')",0)))`

---

Original answer:

Criteria 1:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(A:A,SEARCH("apple",A:A))))`

Criteria 2:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(A:A,ISERROR(SEARCH("apple",A:A)))))`

This gives unpredictable results when referencing cells with clickable URLs in. IMO, this is a bug associated specifically with the FILTER function, and how it parses URLs. QUERY works around this because (again, IMO) it will first convert the source data to a single data type (in this case text) in each referenced column.

Comment: On second look, there seems to be an issue with your answer I have not yet been able to pinpoint. See the doc. I have added https://www.apple.com/ "twice" to Column A and it seems to not be counting the second one as a duplicate. However, pasting more of them "are" for some reason counted as duplicates. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: You'll see it displays 4 upon refresh, but as you make certain changes to the spreadsheet, it changes to the correct 3. Then, upon refresh it is still 3, until the apple.com link is pasted again and the process starts over.... why is this happening and how can I prevent that?

Comment: It would appear that is a genuine bug - I have seen that sort of behaviour before, too. Is it only URLs that seem to break it?

Comment: As far as I am seeing so far, yes-- it is only URLs. Unfortunately, that is the final product in which I will need to paste for a unique count. Can you help me think of any alternative function?

Comment: See if this makes any difference: `=COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(QUERY(A:A,"select A where A contains 'apple'",0)))`

Comment: Holy Crap! It works like a dream! You are the man and thank you so much. What should I do for the "not contains?" I tried ""select A where A not like 'apple'" but this SQL isn't cooperating like how I'm used to. p.s. be sure to update your answer so I can choose it-- maybe even leave your previous response for others not running into this hyperlink bug.